# Como comparar se o conteúdo de duas colunas string de um data frame são parecidas

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um data frame onde preciso comparar quanto o conteúdo de duas colunas são parecidos.

Por Exemplo: `coluna a = “José Luiz da Silva”` e `coluna b = “José L. Silva”`. Como posso fazer para indicar que a coluna a e a coluna b são parecidas?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai uma possível solução, em Python:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from unidecode import unidecode

ignore_list = ['de', 'do', 'da', 'dos', 'das']

def parse_name(full_name):
    name_list = full_name.split() # Separa cada nome
    new_name_list = []
    for name in name_list: # Percorre cada nome
        name = name.strip('.') # Remove pontos
        name = name.lower() # Converte todas as letras em minúsculas
        if name in ignore_list: # Remove preposições
            continue
        name = unidecode(name.decode('utf8')) # Remove acentos (necessita da biblioteca 'unidecode')
        new_name_list.append(name)
    return new_name_list

def is_similar(a, b):
    a = parse_name(a)
    b = parse_name(b)
    if len(a) != len(b): # Se o número de palavras for diferente, retorna falso
        return False
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        if (len(x) == 1) or (len(y) == 1): # Se uma das palavras possuir apenas uma letra...
            if x[0] != y[0]: #...compara apenas a primeira letra
                return False
        else: # Caso contrário...
            if x != y: #...compara a palavra toda
                return False
    return True # Se todas as palavras forem iguais, retorna verdadeiro
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
a = 'José Luiz da Silva'
b = 'José L. Silva'
print is_similar(a, b) # Retorna True
```

Nessa solução, a função `is_similar()` retorna apenas `true` ou `false`. Dependendo da sua necessidade, talvez seja interessante pensar em uma métrica mais flexível, que retorne uma medida de distância. Por exemplo:

- Nomes como `'José L. Silva'` e `'José Luiz da Silva'` teriam distância 0 (seriam considerados iguais);
- Nomes como `'José Silva'` e `'José Luiz da Silva'` teriam um valor de distância pequeno (seriam considerados parecidos);
- Nomes como `'José Silva'` e `'Maria Souza'` teriam um valor de distância grande (seriam considerados bastante diferentes).

Answer (score 1):

([TL;DR](https://repl.it/JKKD/2))

### Testando a taxa de similiaridade entre duas strings:

```
# Testando taxa de similaridade
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def sml(x,y):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, x, y).ratio()

x = 'José Luiz da Silva'
y = 'José L. Silva'
msg = "Taxa de similaridade "

print(msg, 'entre x e y: ', sml(x,y) )
print(msg, 'entre x e x: ', sml(x,x) )
```

**Output:**

```
Taxa de similaridade  entre x e y:  0.7741935483870968
Taxa de similaridade  entre x e x:  1.0
```

[Execute o codigo no repl.it.](https://repl.it/JKKD/2)